# general question regarding .m files and xib 

Tags: xcode

If i have some .m files , that each one of them is belong to a XIB , and implement a code of a specific XIB , and i then load from one .m file -another XIB that works with another .m file ,

so , does the first .m is still implementing  after i load another xib and while working with another .m file ?

I mean , does all my .m files that was loaded in the past, are still working on background?
Because mine, seems to still work while i use others .

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.m files and .xib files are not directly related.

Given your questions I suggest to start with good introduction books, or Apple's documentation ([Cocoa application tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCTutorial/01Introduction/01Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000863) being one of them).

Comment: Look . i have read 2 popular books, i have read documantaion, and i am engineer ,AND i can say - this thing is just unclear to anyone. people here write so many lines of code, and still ask this question. apple dont really explain the small things and differences between lines of code. can you find in apple the difference between addsubview and insertsubview ? at-index subjects ??? i am not a child, and came here to ask questions ,and not to be directed to other places. this is my third question on same subject without one answer. just directions to apple. so i think will help myself.